# Requesting resources when monitoring the resource usage

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I try to monitor my resources and as explained in the documentation [here](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/monitoring.html)

I was able to achieve that as you can see in the code below. My issue is when I have multiple instance of a resource, I cannot figure out how to call an available resource, or wait until one becomes available if they all are busy when requested.

Here is a simple model where an item goes through two tasks sequentially and both tasks are done by the same resource that I have ten instances of. I add the resource instance to a dictionary along with a label showing whether the recorded time was done in the first or second task

```
import simpy
import random


def arrival(env, worker, arrival_time, task1_mean, task1_std, task2_mean, task2_std):
    
    id = 0
    
    while True:
        
        w = first_task(env, worker, task1_mean, task1_std, task2_mean, task2_std, id)
        
        env.process(w)
        
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1/arrival_time))
        
        id += 1


def first_task(env, worker, task1_mean, task1_std, task2_mean, task2_std, id):


    task1_queue = env.now
    with worker[id % len(10)]['time'].request() as req:
        
        task1_start = env.now
        worker[id % len(10)]['task'].append('Task 1')
        
        yield req
        
        yield env.timeout(abs(random.normalvariate(task1_mean, task1_std)))
        task1_end = env.now
    
    w = first_task(env, worker, task2_mean, task2_std, id)
    
    env.process(w)
    

def second_task(env, worker, task2_mean, task2_std, id):

    task2_queue = env.now
    with worker[id % len(10)]['time'].request() as req:
        
        worker[id % len(10)]['task'].append('Task 2')
        task2_start = env.now
        yield req
        
        yield env.timeout(abs(random.normalvariate(task2_mean, task2_std)))
        task2_end = env.now
    

class TimeMonitoredResource(simpy.Resource):
    
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
      
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.start_time = None
    self.end_time = None
    self.working_time = []
    self.starting_time = []
    self.releasing_time = []

  def request(self,*args,**kwargs):
      
    self.start_time = self._env.now

    return super().request(*args,**kwargs)
  
  def release(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.end_time = self._env.now
    self.working_time.append(self.end_time - self.start_time)
    self.starting_time.append(self.start_time)
    self.releasing_time.append(self.end_time)

    return super().release(*args,**kwargs)

def calculate_metrics(op):
    total_operation_time = []
    total_starting_time = []
    total_releasing_time = []
    
    total_operation_time = op.working_time
    total_starting_time = op.starting_time
    total_releasing_time = op.releasing_time
    
    return total_starting_time, total_releasing_time, total_operation_time


env = simpy.Environment()

worker = {}
for i in range(10):
    worker[i] = {'time': TimeMonitoredResource(env, 1), 'task': []}
          
task1_mean, task1_std, task2_mean, task2_std = 6, 2, 8, 2
arrival_time = 2

env.process(arrival(env, worker, arrival_time, task1_mean, task1_std, task2_mean, task2_std))

env.run(1200)


worker_op_start = {}
worker_op_release = {}
worker_op_total = {}
worker_op_task = {}


for i, op in worker.items():
    start, release, total = calculate_metrics(op['time'])
    worker_op_start[i] = start
    worker_op_release[i] = release
    worker_op_release[i] = total
    worker_op_task[i] = op['task']
```

As you can see in this code I used the item id to call one of the ten resources using id % len(10) as a trick to call a specific resource and make the code work. What I want to be able to achieve is calling any of the ten resources to do a task. If all ten are not available, then the process wait until one becomes available.

I tried to use a loop and iterate over the resources and find an available one as follows:

```
for _, resource in worker.items():
    if resource['time'].count == 0:  
        with resource['time'].request() as req:
            resource['task'].append('Task 1')
            yield env.timeout(abs(random.normalvariate(task1_mean, task1_std)))
            yield req
            break
```

Unfortunately, this retuned nothing and all the recorded times were zeros. I hope someone can help with this. Also I want to record the time for each item by id. The question is, is the places where I recorcd those times using env.now() correct or not? As you can see I have task1_queue, task1_start, etc. I just want to make sure I'm recording these times in the right place.

Thank you all. This community has been really helpful in my SimPy journey.

Comment: simpy.Resource do not really have resource objects, they just have a count of available resources.  This means that you cannot track individual simpy.Resource resources.  You need to create a resource object that tracks the info you want, and use a simpy.Store initialized with your resource objects.  I would also create helper get and put fuctions to help with the updating of the resource tracking info.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I create a Store and add the object to it as they are requested and released? But this will lead to the same problem because I don't know what resource to call. I don't want to call a specific one as in my code but rather any available one

Comment: the store is fifo.  when you initialize the store it starts out empty, so you need to add all your resources to the one store as part of start up.  you use the store like any resource pool.  When you are done with a resource will need to return the resource to the store manually (no context manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem with collecting resource metrics at the resource level with a simpy.Resource is simpy.Resource does not have resouce objects.  It only has a count of available / deployed resources.  I created a resource object to collect the metrics and used a simpy.Store to manage the requests.  I wrapped the simpyStore in a class that updates the resource objects as they are requested and released. The issue with a simpy store is that it does not have a context manager to automatically return the resources to the simpy.Store like a simpy.Resouce pool does. So I created a special simpy Event by adding a context manager which wraps the simpy.Store get(), and adds a release call on the "with" exit.  Did not do a lot of testing, but it works in the happy path.  So your getting two things in this example.  a simpy.Store with a context manager the returns resources on exit of the "with", and resources that collect usage metrics at the resource level. This was a bit more trick then I thought it would be.

```
"""
Demo of resources where each resource collects usage data

Composes a resource pool that uses a simpy.Store to hold
resouces objects.  The pool updates the resouce stats as
they are requested and released

Creatd a special event to act as a context manager for
resource requests

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class ResourceEvent(simpy.Event):
    """
    A event for rquesting a resouce.
    Is also a context manager so
    'with' syntax can be use to 
    atomatic release the resource

    event returns a resouce when it succeeds
    """

    def __init__(self, env, request_process, release_process):
        """
        starts the process to get a resouce
        saves processes

        parameters
        ----------
        request_process: process 
            a process to get the resource
        release_process: process
            a process to release a resouce

        """

        super().__init__(env)
        
        self.env = env
        self.request_process = request_process
        self.release_process = release_process

        env.process(self._echo())

    def _echo(self):
        """
            process to get a resouce

            triggers this event when process gets the resouce
            returning the resource
        """
        self.request_event = self.env.process(self.request_process())

        resource = yield self.request_event

        # save resouce so it can be released later
        self.resource = resource

        self.succeed(resource)

    def __enter__(self):
        """
        Context enter, returns self
        """
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, *arg, **karg):
        """
        Context exit

        if the resource request was successful, then
            return the resouce
        else
            cancel the pending resouce request
        """
        if self.request_event.triggered:
            self.release_process(self.resource)
        else:
            self.request_event.cancel()

    
class MyResourcePool():
    """
    Wraps a simpy.Store to behaive more like a simpy.Resouce

    Uses resouces objects that collect usage stats
    """

    def __init__(self, env, recourse_cnt):
        """
        creates a simpy.Store and load it with the desirec
        number of resouces

        parameter
        ---------
        env: simpy.Environment

        resourse_cnt: int
            number of resouces in the pool
        """

        self.env = env
        self._pool = simpy.Store(env)
        self.resources = [] # master list to simplify resouce interation

        for i in range(recourse_cnt):
            resource = self.MyResource(i+1)

            self.resources.append(resource)
            self._pool.put(resource)

    def _request_event(self):
        """
        helper method to get a resouce
        and to update metrics for the resouce
        """

        print(f'{self.env.now} requesting a resouce')

        request_start = self.env.now

        # using a "with" insures the get gets
        # cancled if this process gets canceled
        with self._pool.get() as req:
            resource = yield req

        request_time = self.env.now - request_start
        resource.req_wait_time += request_time

        idle = self.env.now - resource._relase_time
        resource.idle_time += idle

        # save dispatch time to calc the busy/work time later
        resource._dispatch_time = self.env.now

        resource.busy = True

        print(f'{self.env.now} resouce {resource.id} has been deployed')

        return resource


    def request(self):
        """
        Creates a event that returns a resouce when a resouce 
        becomes available

        event is also a context manager so it can be uses 
        in a 'with' syntax
        """

        req = ResourceEvent(self.env, self._request_event, self.release)

        return req
        
        

    def release(self, resource):
        """
        Release a resouce and updates it stats
        """

        print(f'{self.env.now} resouce {resource.id} has been released')

        if resource in self.resources:
            work = self.env.now - resource._dispatch_time
            resource.busy_time += work

            resource._relase_time = self.env.now
            resource.busy = False

            self._pool.put(resource)

        else:
            raise Exception("Trying to release a object that does not belong to pool")


    class MyResource():
        """
        Resouce class for collecting usage stats
        """

        def __init__(self, id):
            """
            initalize collectors and trackers
            """

            self.id = id

            self.busy = False

            self.req_wait_time = 0
            self.busy_time = 0
            self.idle_time = 0

            self._dispatch_time = 0
            self._relase_time = 0

def use_resouce(env, pool):
    """
    test grabing a resource
    """

    with myPool.request() as req:
    
        resource = yield req
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1,3,10))

def test(env, myPool):

    # doing a test without the with syntax
    req = myPool.request()

    resource = yield req

    yield env.timeout(5)

    myPool.release(resource)

    # do real stress test

    for _ in range(20):
        env.process(use_resouce(env, myPool))
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1,1,4))
    


env = simpy.Environment()
myPool = MyResourcePool(env, 3)

env.process(test(env, myPool))

env.run(100)

print()
print('done')
for r in myPool.resources:
    print(f'id: {r.id}, busy: {r.busy_time}, idle: {r.idle_time}, usage: {r.busy_time / (r.busy_time + r.idle_time)}')
```