# simpy Resource attributes

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

Is there a way we can add attributes to simpy Resource objects, and use their values after simulation for further analysis?

For example, in a call centre, I have two agents. I'll declare them as `agents = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)`. I'll call them as  `with agents.request() as req:`.

What I want to do is that I want to give an `id` for each agent and know that which agent attended which call, further for how long each of them were idle, how long were they on call, etc.

Any resource or idea about doing this would be appreciated,

Comment: Short answer: No, not with simpy.Resource.  Create a Agent class with the properties you want and use a simply.Store loaded with 2 Agents instead of simpy.Resource.

Comment: here is a link to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75849508/15294334

Answer (score 0):

old answer where a store with usage tracking objects is wrapped in a class so it behaves more like a simpy.Resource while doing the data colecting automatically

[Requesting resources when monitoring the resource usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75849508/15294334)